# How to show several ProgressBars with different colors on Android 4.x at the same time?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

In my app I'm showing two indeterminate ProgressBars at the same time:

[image]

I set different colors for them.

```
((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.left_progress)).getIndeterminateDrawable()
        .setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.RED, Color.RED));

((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.right_progress)).getIndeterminateDrawable()
        .setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE));
```

But on the screen I see that ProgressBars have only last applied color - blue.

Why? And how to apply to them different colors?

**Update:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/left_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/right_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Update 2:**

This is reproduced only on Android API < 5.x.

Comment: put your xml code for this view

Comment: @Fakher, I updated my question.

Comment: if you try to chnage the blue progress bar to red, does the both of theme change to red ?

Comment: @Fakher, yes, they are.

Comment: try to debug your application and make break points in the 2 lines where you cange the color of your progress bar, and tell me when you reach the first line what the color of the progress bar and in second line what's the color

Comment: @Fakher, how can I do that? ProgressBar doesn't have getColor() method.

Comment: no when you debug you can see the result in your phone !! you don't need to get the color !

Comment: @Fakher, I created two button: one set black color on left_progress, another set blue color on right_progress, default color is gray. When I click on any button, both progressbars change color

Comment: @Fakher, this is reproduced only on Android API < 5.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.left_progress)).getIndeterminateDrawable().mutate()
            .setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.RED, Color.RED));

((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.right_progress)).getIndeterminateDrawable().mutate()
            .setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE));
```

...and this will work

In this code `.mutate()` function call is added.

Here is an article about mutating drawables http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html.

In two words this code is trying to "modify" a drawable which is immutable and shared by its nature.
I just give a quote from the article:

Before mutating we have:

> The following diagram shows what entities are created when you assign the same image resource as the background of two different views. As you can see, two drawables are created but they both share the same constant state, hence the same bitmap:

[image]

And after mutating:

> When you invoke this method on a drawable, the constant state of the drawable is duplicated to allow you to change any property without affecting other drawables. Note that bitmaps are still shared, even after mutating a drawable. The diagram below shows what happens when you invoke mutate() on a drawable:

[image]

Comment: what does .mutate does ??

Comment: @av_lee great answer mate, event with pictures;))